# Sequence minimum value

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sequence

We use several sequences in our product and I see that they're all set with a minimum value of -2147483648. 
I've seen some people note that if you are only using positive numbers, that the minimum should be set to 0 or 1. Is there a problem or cost to setting it to the smallest possible value?

This is the creation code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[XXX_seq] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -2147483648
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE  2 
END
```

Comment: Nope. that's the default behaviour anyway if you don't specify. It doesn't make any difference here unless you allow the sequence to cycle.

Comment: you will lose half of your available range

Comment: Beware the pitfalls in writing `-2147483648` in many languages (C, C++, and Java). In such cases `-2147483648` is **not** a literal, but a compile time constant expression consisting of the unary negation of `2147483648`. The latter cannot fit into a 32 bit signed `int` so you may end up with an unexpected type promotion or other behaviour. Often you'll see `-2147483647 - 1` to obviate that.

Comment: @MarianNasry, are you saying that if we set the minimum to 0 or 1, we can effectively double the range?!?

Comment: @Gidil setting the minimum to 0 or 1 , you will lose the range from -2147483648 to 0 , which is the half of the integer range